# Eclipse content assist not showing method description

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse content assist shows all the suggestions as intended though it doesn't pop up a window showing Javadoc descriptions. What can be done to make the description window start appearing?

I already tried restoring content assist settings to default and restarting Eclipse but that didn't work.

[Picture showing which window I'm talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg3Ki.jpg)

Comment: I'm confused. Is the picture what you want to happen or what is happening?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, yes it shows what I want to happen (found the screenshot on the internet)

Comment: F2 will show doc of the selected element its own, as will the JavaDoc View. Does the doc never show? Is it missing only for certain classes?

Comment: F2 didn't help. I found the solution though, the problem was that the JRE system library inside my project wasn't a jdk. Changing that fixed the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've just found the solution. Turns out my project had a jre as a JRE system library instead of jdk (which unlike jre contains javadoc method descriptions).

The solution was:

1. Go to *Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Add... -> Next (with the Standard VM selected) -> Directory*.
2. Select the jdk folder (which after installing Java Developement Kit is placed in C:\Program Files\Java by default) and click finish.
3. In the Installed JREs table select the jdk and click *Apply and close* (this will set the jdk as the default workspace sdk).
4. Right click on your project and go to *Build Path -> Add libraries... -> Next (with JRE System Library selected) -> select "Workspace default JRE" -> Finish*
5. Right click on the jre library (not the just added jdk) in your project in the Package Explorer and go to *Build path -> Remove from build path*
6. Restart the Eclipse

If you have the jdk already imported to the worspace you can probably skip first few steps and just switch the JRE inside your project.